# PHP PDO Представить обычный запрос в виде подготовленного

Tags: php, pdo

Срочно требуется небольшая помощь, есть код

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);

$date = $_GET["date"];

$datestart = "SELECT DISTINCT game.ID_Game , game.date , game.place , game.score FROM game WHERE game.date > '". $date ."'";

foreach ($dbh->query($datestart) as $row) {
    echo $row['ID_Game'];
    echo "&nbsp;";
    echo $row['date'];
    echo "&nbsp;";
    echo $row['place'];
    echo "&nbsp;";
    echo $row['score'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Нужно переделать обычный запрос под подготовленное выражение с сохранением функционала. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Да пожалуйста, приходите еще.

Comment: Ну в общем и целом хотя вопрос и абсолютно ленивый, но для сайта законный поскольку Stack Overflow именно для таких вопросов и задумывался - "как сделать", а не "памагитя, у меня ничего не работает".

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы представить обычный запрос в виде подготовленного, надо сделать 4 вещи:

1. [Нормально соединиться](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql), а не одной строчкой
2. Заменить все переменные в запросе на знаки вопроса
3. Подготовить запрос с помощью prepare()
4. И выполнить его, передав переменные в execute() в виде массива

то есть так:

```
<?php

require 'pdo.php';

$sql = "SELECT ID_Game, date, place, score FROM game WHERE game.date > ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$_GET["date"]]);
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo $row['ID_Game'];
}
```

в итоге получится тот же самый стейтмент, который был у тебя в результате предыдущего запроса, который модно либо перебирать с помощью foreach, либо из которого можно либо фетчить результат с помощью

- fetchColumn() - получить одну ячейку, удобно для запросов count(*)
- fetch() - одну строку
- fetchAll() - массив строк, причем формат этого массива может быть разным